# RxJava: Combine 2 lists, ignoring missing items in list 2

Tags: java, android-studio, rx-java

I have two lists of objects, RemoteList and LocalList.
While my app is offline, remote users can be adding and deleting objects from the RemoteList while local users are editing the LocalList.
When the app becomes connected again, it should sync the two lists.
[Marble Diagram showing how the lists should be merged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrcjl.jpg)



For example, here are the object ids in each list before syncing:
RemoteList: 0, 1, 2 (deleted), 3 (new), 4 (new)
LocalList:  0, 1 (delete), 2, 3 (new)

When syncing, the ids have to be changed to prevent having two separate objects with the same id.

MergedList: 0, 3, 4, 5 (local id 3 was changed to 5)

I'm experimenting with RxJava, so a quick point in the right direction would be great. Merge? Fork? A combination? Maybe using Filter and adding a field to Object like isSynced?

Answer (score 0):

Get each list in the form of `Single<List<X>>`, where X is a record that indicates what happened to a particular item, and `zip` them together. Now you can walk both lists and do your combination logic synchronously:

```java
record Item(int id, boolean added, boolean deleted) { }

Single<List<Item>> remoteListSource = ...
Single<List<Item>> localListSource = ...

Single.<List<Item>>zip(remoteListSource, localListSource, 
(remoteList, localList) -> {

    Set<Integer> deleted = new HashSet<>();

    // collect deleted ids
    remoteList.stream()
        .filter(item -> item.deleted)
        .forEach(item -> deleted.add(item.id));
    localList.stream()
        .filter(item -> item.deleted)
        .forEach(item -> deleted.add(item.id));

    Set<Integer> duplicate = new HashSet<>();
    List<Item> result = new ArrayList<>();

    // go through both lists, ignoring deleted ids
    Stream.concat(remoteList.stream(), localList.stream())
    .filter(item -> !deleted.contains(item.id))
    .forEach(item -> {
         // id already seen?
         if (duplicate.contains(item.id)) {
             // if this is an addition, generate new item
             if (item.added) {
                 
                 item = new Item(Collections.max(duplicate) + 1, true, false);
                 duplicate.add(item.id);
                 result.add(item);
             } else {
                 // else we have an unmodified item already in result
                 // nothing to do
             }
         } else {
             // was not a duplicate, remember it
             duplicate.add(item.id);
             result.add(item);
         }
    });

    return result;
})
.subscribe(combinedList -> { /* ... */ });
```